# How to protect wp-admin through .htaccess?

Tags: security

I'd like to protect the /wp-admin/ directory at the server level.  This means two logins.  One through the server and another through WordPress.

I believe this can be handled through .htaccess.  Does anyone know how?

Also, are there any files that will need access (i.e., admin-ajax.php)?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it should look like this:

```
AuthType     Basic
AuthName     NAME_THIS_THING
AuthUserFile PATH_TO_USER_FILE
<Files '*'>
    Require valid-user
</Files>
<Files 'admin-ajax.php'>
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</Files>
```

Replace the upper case parts with something real. `admin-ajax.php` is the only file that should be available without restriction.

The [details of the user file](http://www.technotrade.com/htaccess.html) are a little bit out of our scope, and they might depend on your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing so, you can use this code to prevent others from opening your login page;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
</IfModule>
```

(Replace xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with your current IP)